# How do I mollify an indicator function with $x \in$ $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis, regularization

Good morning,

I have to find this function : $\gamma (x) = 1, \left | x \right | \leqslant 1 ,  x \in  \mathbb{R}^n$, $\gamma \in C^\infty (\mathbb{R}^n)$
On some subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ we can find that also : $\gamma (x) = 0$
However, I was told to use bump functions but every example I found was in $\mathbb{R}$.

The problem is that it is the first question of my exercise, and the next question, is
"Show that you can find $\varpi \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and  $\widehat{\varpi} = \gamma$"
I supposed I could take $\varpi$ = $\widehat{\gamma}$, but I am not sure...

If you could help me, it would be nice

Comment: If $\varphi(t)$ is your 1-dim bump function with $\varphi(t)=1$ if $-1\le t\le 1$ and ·$\varphi(t)=0$ if $t>2$ or $t<-2$ (for example), just take $\Phi(x)=\varphi(|x|^2)$ (where $|x|$ denotes the euclidean norm).

Comment: Sorry, I did not take the right letter, it is $\widehat{\varpi}$ = $\gamma$ and $\varpi$ = $\widehat{\gamma}$